# Pivoting table with separation of columns

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

Below you can see a short example of my table.

```
    library(data.table)
    library(dplyr)
Table2<-structure(list(Participant = c("ER", "EA"), Country = c("Belgium", 
                                                                "Bulgaria"), Y_0_4.Male = c(0, 0), Y_0_4.Female = c(0, 0), Y_5_9.Male = c(0, 
                                                                                                                                          3), Y_5_9.Female = c(5, 0), Total = c(5, 3), Data = c(2018, 2018
                                                                                                                                          )), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"
                                                                                                                                          ))
```

[image]

Now I want to do two things with my table.

The first is to separate columns that contain age (e.g Y_0_4  and Y_5_9 ) in separate columns with the title Age, and
The second is to separate titles that contain words Female and Male in two separate columns.Below you how it looks like the table.

[image]

So can anybody help me how to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `pivot_longer` from `tidyr`:

```r
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

pivot_longer(Table2, matches('\\.'), names_sep = '\\.', names_to = c('Age', '.value')) %>%
  mutate(Total = Male + Female)
#> # A tibble: 4 x 7
#> Participant Country  Total  Data Age    Male Female
#> <chr>       <chr>    <dbl> <dbl> <chr> <dbl>  <dbl>
#> 1 ER          Belgium      0  2018 Y_0_4     0      0
#> 2 ER          Belgium      5  2018 Y_5_9     0      5
#> 3 EA          Bulgaria     0  2018 Y_0_4     0      0
#> 4 EA          Bulgaria     3  2018 Y_5_9     3      0
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `melt()` from the `data.table` library:

**Reprex**

- Code

```r
library(data.table)

melt(Table2, 
     id.vars = c("Participant", "Country", "Data"),
     measure.vars = patterns("\\d\\.M", "\\d\\.F"),
     variable.name = "Age",
     value.name = c("Male", "Female"))[, `:=` (Age = tstrsplit(grep("\\d\\.[MF]", names(Table2), value = TRUE),"\\.")[[1]], Total = Male + Female)][order(Country),][]
```

- Output

```r
#>    Participant  Country Data   Age Male Female Total
#> 1:          ER  Belgium 2018 Y_0_4    0      0     0
#> 2:          ER  Belgium 2018 Y_5_9    0      5     5
#> 3:          EA Bulgaria 2018 Y_0_4    0      0     0
#> 4:          EA Bulgaria 2018 Y_5_9    3      0     3
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>